# Apache server config redirect from IP to domain name EC2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I am running an apache webserver on a linux EC2 instance.

The problem is that you can access the server using the IP address, DNS and the domain name. This causes a problem for SEO and I want to tidy it up.

I have read on the apache documentation that you can do a mod_rewrite and this needs to be done in the httpd.conf if you have root access otherwise in the .htaccess for per directory override. 
I have root access so I am trying to change the  httpd.conf

If the user types in 
http://52.17.12.123/
or
http://ec2-52.17.12.123.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

I want them to be redirected to 
www.example.com

This is what I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/my-website"
 # Other directives here
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^52.17.12.123.com$
 RewriteRule /* http://www.example.com/ [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems to partially work but www.example.com does not load due to to many redirects.

--EDIT--
Thanks, so now in my **httpd.conf** I now have the following configuration

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:80

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/my-website"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

It is all working correctly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It seems to partially work`.
I doubt, considering the rule you currently have in your `httpd.conf`.

You can have it this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, I have edited my main question the results of what you suggested. The problem is that if put in http://52.17.12.123/pricing.html I get redirected to http://pricing.html/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've edited my answer, should be working as expected now